# CoreData: How to fetch a specific object using a predicate

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-data

**The situation:**

I fetch a complete table from  my sqllite core data database and show it in a TableView like this:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyTable"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

**The Challenge:**

How do I get the EntryID and fetch the specific entry from the database (e.g. if i click on an entry)? I think this goes in the right direction?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(id = %@)", myEntryID];
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you have an entry object called `entry`, it would be a predicate like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(SELF = %@)", entry];
```

Which is roughly equivalent to

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(objectID = %@)", entry.objectID];
```

For a `NSManagedObjectID`, you get something like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(objectID = %@)", myEntryID];
```

Comment: +1 If you have to use a predicate, this is the way to go.  Otherwise, `-[NSManagedObjectContext objectWithID:]` would probably be better.

Comment: Of course, but for e.g. `NSFetchedResultsController` you have to use a predicate.

Comment: The "self" keyword also works if you are fetching *multiple* objects per their objectIDs: `NSPredicate *predicateForFetch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self IN %@)", arrayOfNSManagedObjectIDs];`

Comment: I get `NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath objectID not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Report id=7>'` if I use `objectID`.

Comment: @Benjohn I got the same but you can compare SELF against the objectID instead. `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(SELF = %@)", objectID];`

Comment: Be aware of you cannot use SELF and objectID in predicate formatted with key: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(%K = %@)", @"self", entry];`

Answer (score 10):

This is proper predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF = %@", objectID];
```

Where `objectID` is `NSManagedObjectID` instance.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at `-[NSManagedObject objectID]` and `-[NSManagedObjectContext objectWithID:]`.

Answer (score 2):

When you build the table you do so either with an array returned by a fetch or by the implicit array inside a `NSFetchResultsController`. Therefore, the object you want has the same index in the array/controller as it does in the table.

So, it becomes simply a matter of calling:

```
myObject=[fetchedArray objectAtIndex:tableRowIndex];
```

or

```
myObject=[myFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:tableRowIndex];
```

This is the real genius of the UITable. It always reflects the data model precisely. You never have to translate back and forth between the table indexes and your data model indexes.