# Core Data: Keypath "objectID" not found in entity

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` with a predicate to load a list of `Documents` in my application. I want to load all the `Documents` except the currently active one.

I am using Rentzsch's [MOGenerator](http://rentzsch.com/code/mogenerator) to create a `_Document` class and then I put all my custom code in the `Document` subclass. `_Document` generates an `objectID` property with type `DocumentID`.

In the class that creates the controller, I set the controller's `currentDocID` property:

```
controller.currentDocID = self.document.objectID;
```

In the controller itself, I lazy load the fetchedResultsController like this:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Document" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(objectID != %@)", self.currentDocID];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateModified" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

When the fetchedResultsController loads, my app crashes with an unhandled exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath objectID not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Document id=1>'
```

It's my understanding that all NSManagedObjects have an objectID, whether temporary or permanent. Is this not the case? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your predicate to read

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self != %@", [self currentDoc]]
```

Where `currentDoc` is a reference to the instance of the `NSManagedObject` that represents the current document.

Core Data will do the equality check internally.

Comment: Do you know why `...@"self != %@", [self currentDoc]]` is not the same like `...@"(objectID != %@)", self.currentDocID]`. According to this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/2306550/647644 it should be equivalent.