# keypath objectID not found in entity exception

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa, core-data

I'm facing this strange issue when trying to fetch some objects after their objectID. The error complains that there is no such thing as an objectID key path, but the managed object should respond to that. The error is not thrown all the time, which makes me think it could be a concurrency problem, although I've double checked and each context performs the operations on its own thread.

Here is the predicate, although it looks sane to me:
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectID == %@", book.objectID]`

Edit: Regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493108/core-data-keypath-objectid-not-found-in-entity?rq=1) answer. I didn't tried using the object itself, I need to use the objectID because of multithreading considerations.

Comment: the answer given still hold for this case. although strange, CoreData allow comparison of objects to their `objectID` in a predicate as this is how they are identified in any case.

Comment: @DanShelly not sure what you mean by "still hold", sharing managed objects between threads doesn't seem like a good idea

Comment: I did not said you should share managed objects between threads. I meant that you could still use the predicate given in the linked answer, but provide it your object ID as parameter: `@"SELF = %@",book.objectID`

Comment: @DanShelly Strange enough, that works. Thanks! Any idea why? If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer given in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493108/core-data-keypath-objectid-not-found-in-entity?rq=1) link still holds here.
It holds in the sense that you use the same predicate:

```
NSPredicate* p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF = %@",book.objectID];
```

But you supply the `objectID` as parameter.

CoreData allow comparison of `objectID`s and objects when fetching from the store. it probably has to do with the fact that an `objectID` is used for a one-to-one mapping to a managed object (hence the use of SELF which is a predicate reserved word and not a property name).

Comment: Another example of an obscure behavior of Core Data. I wonder is this even documented anywhere? I've been struggling with this error until I found your comment.